# Required Field Validators firing in Chrome & Safari when button has CausesValidation="false"

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, safari, validation

I'm having some problems with my ASP.NET 4 application in Chrome & Safari (works in Firefox and IE).

I have a button declared using the following code:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnEOI1" runat="server" CssClass="buttonCSS" Text="Lodge an Expression of Interest"
                        OnClick="btnEOI_Click" CausesValidation="False" />
```

In the code-behind file I have the following code:

```
protected void btnEOI_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Response.Redirect("Default.aspx", true);
}
```

Also on the page is a LoginControl that has two RequiredFieldValidators and a RegularExpressionValidator:

```
<asp:requiredfieldvalidator id="UserNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" 
    ErrorMessage="Please enter your User Name." SetFocusOnError="true" Display="None">
</asp:requiredfieldvalidator>

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" id="RegularExpressionValidator1"  
    ControlToValidate="UserName"
    ErrorMessage="Please enter your User Name without spaces." ValidationExpression="[\S]+" 
    Display="None" SetFocusOnError="true" >
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>                                 

<asp:requiredfieldvalidator id="PasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" 
    ErrorMessage="Please enter your Password." SetFocusOnError="true" Display="None">
</asp:requiredfieldvalidator>
```

When I click the button in Chrome and Safari, the UserNameRequired and PasswordRequired validators fire even though the button has CausesValidation="false".  The validation errors do not occur in IE or Firefox.

How can I stop the validators from firing in Chrome and Firefox?

Comment: Do you have update to the latest asp.net ajax library ?

Comment: We currently use the standard libraries installed with .NET Framework 4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that we had some javascript used to prevent double-clicking that was submitting form[0] (which in this case is the login control).

Comment: I'm having the same problem with a RadioButtonList http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248780/required-field-validator-with-safari-5-1 where the validation is firing once the user selects a value from the list, but doesn't click the submit button.

Did you get to the root cause of this issue?

Comment: @suggy1982 - in my case it was because we were doing a submit on form[0] in some javascript.  After removing that code we've had no issue between browsers.  I read your question - it's a strange problem.  I use the wizard control in a few places and find it's difficult to work with at times.

Answer (score 1):

I have just tested your code in an empty page and it works correctly in all browsers.

Nervetheless you could try using [Validation Groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx).

Just set the same group for UserNameRequired, RegularExpressionValidator1, PasswordRequired and your login button.

Comment: Sorry for the delay - putting all of the validators into a Validation Group did not resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this is relevant in your problem but have found problems with `RequiredFieldValidators` with `Display="Dynamic"` set for it.

Removing it fixed a problem I had where some validators were not displaying properly in `Chrome`. Whereas there have been other instances in the past where adding helped solve a problem.